# markdown escape setext h1

Tags: escaping, markdown

The below lines are markdown `setext` headers escaped with a single leading `backslash`, this post is parsed as markdown so it's an excellent showcase, it works fine for a `h2` level header, but fails for the `h1` level header.

Text prior to markdown parsing, no trailing whitespaces for newlines:

```
This is an H1
\=============

This is an H2
\-------------
```

Text output from markdown parsing:

This is an H1
\=============

This is an H2
-------------

I'm aware of the flavour issues with markdown, and the originals lacking specifications and implementation spawning them. Still, what is the correct way to escape a `h1` level `setext` header in markdown, if at all possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple things going on here.

First of all,  neither line is recognized as a setext header because of the extra character. In order words, you could use any character that is not a `=` or `-` and it would cause the parser to consider the text to be a paragraph rather than a header.

Secondly, the hyphen (`-`) is an [escapable character](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#backslash) while the equal sign (`=`) is not. However, this processing is most likely done as inline markup, not at the block level (when parsing for header vs. paragraph). What happens is that the string `\-` is replaced with `-` after all other processing is done. In order words, it is a fluke that it works for the level 2 headers.

If you want [horizontal rules](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#hr), then you need to have a blank line before the lines, which removes the need to escape anything (or course escaping would also cause the parser to not recognize the line as a horizontal rule). By the way, only hyphens (underscores & asterisks), not equal signs, can be used for horizontal rules, which is why equal signs are not escapable.

If you just want the raw characters to display in a paragraph, then avoid the newline, which won't show in the Browser anyway. Like this:

```
This is an H1 =============

This is an H2 -------------
```

If you want the line to actually appear on a separate line, then you could use some raw HTML to insert a `<br>` tag:

```
This is an H1<br>=============

This is an H2<br>-------------
```

Or possibly even:

```
This is an H1
<br>=============

This is an H2
<br>-------------
```

Note that in that last case you get easy to read Markdown and the `<br>` tag accomplishes the same thing as the backslash. It causes the parser to not see it as a setext header. But is also gives consistent results across levels and even preserves the line break in the output.